# Как сделать базу данных для нескольких пользователей?

Tags: база-данных, json, сервер

Приложение является сервисом для прохождения тестов (психология). Встал вопрос, чтобы было несколько пользователей, каждый из которых имеет независимую базу данных по своим опросам. Сейчас структура БД очень проста:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "ma****@mail.ru",
      "password": "********",
      "name": "Администратор"
    }
  ],
  "persons": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Марина",
      "middleName": "Сергеевна",
      "surname": "Бондарь",
      "date": "12.06.2018 19:49:02",
      "gender": "female"
    },
    {
      "name": "Иван",
      "middleName": "Петрович",
      "surname": "Петров",
      "gender": "male",
      "date": "13.02.2019 19:23:43",
      "id": 5
    }
  ],
  "paei": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "date": "17.02.2019 08:53:25",
      "skillP": 17,
      "skillA": 29,
      "skillE": 41,
      "skillI": 23
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "date": "17.02.2019 09:00:37",
      "skillP": 18,
      "skillA": 29,
      "skillE": 36,
      "skillI": 27
    }
   ]
 }
```

Использую json-server.

users - это администраторы

persons - это люди из списка для тестирования

paei - это результаты конкретного теста, привязанные к id человека из списка persons

Теперь в чем я не смог разобраться:

1) достаточно ли мне будет использовать json-server, потянет ли она базу данных из нескольких десятков тысяч json-объектов

2) можно ли динамически добавлять в БВ таблицы. Например, если я сделаю структуру БД такую, что каждый администратор bp из списка users будет иметь одинаковый набор таблиц? То есть у каждого будут свои таблицы persons и paei

3) а как же правильно делать такую БД? В туториалах по мессенджерам я видел схему, когда набор таблиц для всех одинаковый, но идет привязка по id пользователя

Comment: 10к - это не нагрузка. Если бы вы сказали 100 миллионов, то тут да. Делать БД или таблицы в БД для каждого пользователя глупо. В туториалах всё правильно сделано

Comment: @ArchDemon вы заметили, что речь идет про json-server - инструмент для быстрого прототипирования и тестирования, а не полноценную СУБД?

Comment: автор, зачем вы используете вещи не по назначению? Это ПО не предназначено для ваших целей.

Comment: потому и спросил... здесь сильно "бьют" за вопросы? :-D